# Uploading photos to a group - Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to upload a bunch of photos from your phone to a fb group using Graph API.

From my research, I can find only old posts on this topic. Is uploading photos to a group not supported anymore? If so, is there any work around for this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/group/feed#publish

You can´t upload photos to a group with the API. I can´t remember that it was ever possible. And you would need publish_actions and user_groups to post something on the group wall, but you will not get user_groups approved: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-user_groups

Comment: Thank you for the info. Appreciate it :)